# Azure-CLI Blob Storage remove multiple blobs

Tags: bash, for-loop, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I need to remove multiple files/blobs with the Azure-CLI. But it's not officially supported. So I wrote a for-loop to remove multiple files with the az command. It's look like this:

```
for i in `az storage blob list --container-name $BUCKET --output table | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do
    if az storage blob delete --name $i --container-name $BUCKET --output table ; then
      echo "Files inside the bucket (container) ${BUCKET} have been erased"
    else
      echo "Unable to erase the files inside the bucket (container) ${BUCKET}." && exit 1
    fi
done
```

But this doesn't work correctly and I think the loop hangs. But I don't know why.

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thanks for your help. But nothing happen. I'm working on Xubuntu 17.04 and had fresh installed the azure cli.

I get this Message, if I CTRL+C:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/SenderBase.py", line 118, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open

    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1253, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 703, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/telemetry.py", line 271, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/telemetry.py", line 263, in upload_telemetry
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/applicationinsights/TelemetryClient.py", line 55, in flush
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/TelemetryChannel.py", line 71, in flush
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/SynchronousQueue.py", line 39, in flush
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/applicationinsights/channel/SenderBase.py", line 118, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1253, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 703, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It's totaly unnecessary where I run this script. I get always the same error :-(

--aruka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, your script works for me, maybe we can try this script:

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=jasontest321
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=+v6/ZQy74QhIwdvEMbnMV7HMaDaNUAkCDizBTOVdZkBUlw==
export container_name=vhds
for i in `az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do
    if az storage blob delete --name $i --container-name $container_name >/dev/null ; then
      echo "Files $i inside the $container_name have been erased"
    else
      echo "Unable to erase the files $i inside the  $container_name." && exit 1
    fi
done
```

Here is the screenshot about the result:

[image]

**Update:**

```
#az --version
.
role (2.0.5)
sf (1.0.2)
sql (2.0.4)
storage (2.0.7)
vm (2.0.7)

Python (Linux) 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]

Python location '/root/lib/azure-cli/bin/python'
[root@jasoncli@jasonye ~]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

In my lab, my root account version is 2.7.5. we should check your python version for your user `aruka`.

---

**Update2:**
We can use Azure portal [cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) to test this script:
[image]

**Update3:**

```
root@jasonvm:~# history
    1  echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ wheezy main" |      sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list
    2  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 417A0893
    3  sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
    4  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install azure-cli
    5  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=jasondisk321
    6  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=O1/xxxWRzOlWep78iRcxxx/htgxHImKxxytlsv7gnn0hg1aGvw==
    7  export container_name=vhds
    8  for i in `az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do     if az storage blob delete --name $i --container-name $container_name >/dev/null ; then       echo "Files $i inside the $container_name have been erased";     else       echo "Unable to erase the files $i inside the  $container_name." && exit 1;     fi; done
    9  az login -u jason.ye@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com -p xxxx
   10  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=jasondisk321
   11  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=O1/2D1UxeGcOlWep78iRcR5PxxgxxxzRbWoytlsv7gnn0hg1aGvw==
   12  export container_name=vhds
   13  for i in `az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do     if az storage blob delete --name $i --container-name $container_name >/dev/null ; then       echo "Files $i inside the $container_name have been erased";     else       echo "Unable to erase the files $i inside the  $container_name." && exit 1;     fi; done
   14  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=jasondisk321
   15  export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=O1/2D1UC0xxx/ztABmMyQFCeGcWRzOlWep78iRcR5Pt/K9yKxMT/htgxHImKqgznzRbWoytlsv7gnn0hg1aGvw==
   16  export container_name=vhds
   17  for i in `az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1,2d' | sed '/^$/d'` ; do     if az storage blob delete --name $i --container-name $container_name >/dev/null ; then       echo "Files $i inside the $container_name have been erased";     else       echo "Unable to erase the files $i inside the  $container_name." && exit 1;     fi; done
   18  history
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the error message to my original post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you run this command `az storage blob list --container-name $container_name --output table`? by the way, please run this command to show the CLI version `az --version`

Comment: I've posted an answer :-)

Comment: @aruka I have update my answer about how to use cloud shell to test that script, please check it:)

Comment: Yes, I have just posted, that it works like a charm. Don't know whats going on on my systems, that its not working there

Comment: @aruka maybe we should re-install python and CLI 2.0, then test it again. By the way, if my answer is helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Comment: Okay, I will try. Should I install Python from sources oder with apt?

Comment: Yes, we can use apt to install python. please refer to this [case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-newer-python-versions-using-apt-get).

Comment: Which version should I install? Sorry for the many questions :-D

Comment: @aruka we can install version 3.5 python:)

Comment: I've made two vm with Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS. There I installed Python 3.6 from sources or with the link you posted. With Ubuntu the first time it ran perfectly. The second time it wont and stuck at the beginning of the command. On CentOS nothing worked for me. Really, I don't know what's the problem with this script. On a fresh system the command won't work...Do you have any idea, what can help?

Comment: @aruka Do you mean you create Azure VMs to test it, and it does not work for you? I have create Azure VM ubuntu 16.04, and install cli 2.0 on it, it works fine, I will update my command history to it, please check it.

Comment: No, I mean I create two local VMs with VirtualBox and tested there. But I can also test with a VM from Azure. I must look how comparable it will be, because my other clouds I tested from my local machine ^^

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've created a VM on AWS (because I should use AWS; its a task of my masters thesis) with Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed all from scratch and what should I say: It works like a charm. I really don't know what's the problem with my desktop-ubuntu. But in on a ec2-instance all went fine. But it would be helpful, if Microsoft can implement a function like delete-batch, similar to upload-batch and download-batch. If I have any more problems I will sent a message here :-)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of tips (unrelated to the root of the issue which is why the delete commands hang) - you don't have to use the sed/awk dance to get the blob name. There is a specific output format (tsv) that is intended to give you a more scripting friendly output (no headers or other distracting things to exclude). Combined with --query, you can then select which fields of the output you are interested in:

```
az storage blob list -c templates --account-name johanstetemplates --query "[].name" --output tsv
```

will give you the list of blobs in the given container.

Personally, I'm partial to using xargs if I want to process many items in parallel and control things like how many concurrent requests I make etc.

```
    az storage blob list -c templates --account-name johanstetemplates --query "[].name" --output tsv | xargs -L1 -P10 -I{} az storage blob show -c templates --account-name johanstetemplates -n {}
```

(I changed the delete command to show to prevent users from blindly copy/paste the command and get very upset when all their blobs got deleted)

Answer (score 0):

The first command (on my own azure):

```
$ az storage blob list --container-name testbucket --output table
Name         Blob Type      Length  Content Type    Last Modified
-----------  -----------  --------  --------------  -------------------------
results.csv  BlockBlob         254  text/csv        2017-08-02T22:30:05+00:00
```

And the version:

```
$ az --version
azure-cli (2.0.12)

acr (2.0.9)
acs (2.0.11)
appservice (0.1.11)
batch (3.0.3)
billing (0.1.3)
cdn (0.0.6)
cloud (2.0.7)
cognitiveservices (0.1.6)
command-modules-nspkg (2.0.1)
component (2.0.6)
configure (2.0.10)
consumption (0.1.3)
container (0.1.7)
core (2.0.12)
cosmosdb (0.1.11)
dla (0.0.10)
dls (0.0.11)
feedback (2.0.6)
find (0.2.6)
interactive (0.3.7)
iot (0.1.10)
keyvault (2.0.8)
lab (0.0.9)
monitor (0.0.8)
network (2.0.11)
nspkg (3.0.1)
profile (2.0.9)
rdbms (0.0.5)
redis (0.2.7)
resource (2.0.11)
role (2.0.9)
sf (1.0.5)
sql (2.0.8)
storage (2.0.11)
vm (2.0.11)

Python (Linux) 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118]

Python location '/home/aruka/lib/azure-cli/bin/python'
```

Comment: Please run this command to find the python path, `which python`.  Or type `python` and check the python version.

Comment: Hi,

`$ which python
/usr/bin/python`

`$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But its the same: Nothing happen...
I don't know what's the problem?!?! It should run :-(

Comment: According to this error message, it seems the main thread is closed and the child thread is not closed. please use `set -x`  and run this script again, to find more details about this script.

Comment: Where should I use `set -x` in the script?

Comment: Or do you have another solution to delete more than one blob with one command? It doesn't need to be that script, that I posted :-)

Comment: we should install a new Python 3 interpreter package and many things
will work because the Ubuntu infrastructure shares pure-Python modules across
all installed Python 3's. More information about this issue, please refer to this link   http://bugs.python.org/issue29307#msg285730

Comment: For now, we can't delete all blobs with a single command, we should use loop to delete them. by the way, maybe we can use Azure portal to delete all blobs, we can select all blobs in the container, and delete them all.

Comment: Okay, so I should install Python 3 from sources or another Package or is it at the moment not possible with Ubuntu? Its not an option to delete the blobs with the portal, I must use a script for my thesis for a performance measurement. And one task is to delete the whole content of a bucket/container.

Comment: Do you have windows PC? we can use powershell to delete all blobs.

Comment: Nope, I only use Linux and the whole Script works only on Linux. Do you think it work with another Distribution like Debian, Fedora or Arch?

Comment: I am use centos 7.3, works fine, ubuntu 16.04 works fine too,

Comment: Okay, but than I don't understand the problems with Python 3.6. How did you install the azure-cli?

Comment: I follow this [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli#apt-get-for-debianubuntu) to install CLI 2.0,

Comment: For test, we can use Azure portal [cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) to test that script.